# How to send different RAML response with different input query parameters

Tags: api, mule, raml, mule-esb

I have a question related to RAML sending different response. In the below RAML, I want to send the response based on the query parameter. If my query parameter (flightId) is "F001", I should get a response only for the data F001. But I am getting the response with all the data specified in the response. May I know how to filter the unwanted data.

```
#%RAML 1.0
baseUri: https://mocksvc.mulesoft.com/mocks/9b7a0390-ecf4-4ff4-b307-0b7d87ed9495 # baseUri: https://mocksvc.mulesoft.com/mocks/b133e2e4-f0e3-49a0-b224-8f36358e04ca # 
title: FlightApi-Rajesh
version: 1.0.1
/{flightId}:
description: Flight Id
get:

  queryParameters:
    flightId: 
      displayName: flightId
      type: string
      required: true
      description: Flight name with its ID
      example: F0001

  description: Get the flight with `flightId = {flightId}`

  responses:
    200:
      body:
        application/json:
          example: |
            {
              "F001":{
                "flightName": "Ingido",
                "Location": "Mumbai",
                "flightId": "F001",
                "Destination":"Delhi",
                "timing":"19:55 HRS"
            },
            "F002":{
              "flightName": "SpiceJet",
                "Location": "Pune",
                "flightId": "PNQ012",
                "Destination":"Chennai",
                "timing":"15:00 HRS"
            }
            }
    404:
      body:
        application/json:
          example: |
            {"message": "Flight not found"}
```

Answer (score 2):

RAML is a design specification for REST APIs. When you run the mock service based on RAML, it does not have the capability of generating dynamic responses, which is what you are trying to do. Please refer Mule forum which confirms this - https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/60487/can-the-example-in-the-raml-be-dynamic.html

If your requirement is to create a mock service with dynamic responses, there are other ways to achieve implementing such mock services - SOAPUI, Dynatrace, etc.

- http://blog.maheeka.me/2016/11/parasoft-virtualizer-tips-for.html
- https://www.soapui.org/rest-testing-mocking/service-mocking-overview.html

If your requirement is to use RAML and try dynamic responses, you will have to create a Mule ESB project based off the RAML. You can then implement dynamic responses based on input received with Mule configurations.

http://workshop.tools.mulesoft.com/modules/module3_lab1#step-1-create-a-new-mule-project-and-import-raml-definition

Comment: Thanks maheeka. That helps.

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely want to change your example to this. A mock endpoint will return your example response every time, so if you're only expecting one match, the example should reflect that. Keep this in mind, because *you will not be able to modify the response of a mocked API based on user input*:

```
/{flightId}:
  description: Flight Id
  get:
    queryParameters:
      flightId: 
        displayName: flightId
        type: string
        required: true
        description: Flight name with its ID
        example: F0001
  responses:
    200:
      body:
        application/json:
          example: |
            {
              "F001":{
                "flightName": "Ingido",
                "Location": "Mumbai",
                "flightId": "F001",
                "Destination":"Delhi",
                "timing":"19:55 HRS"
              }
            }
    404:
      body:
        application/json:
          example: |
            {"message": "Flight not found"}
```

If you have received this data from the database connector, even with a single record returned, you'll get a list of results. You'll need to transform it like this:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json

%vars flight = (payload filter $.flightId == flowVars.flightId)[0]
---
{
  (flowVars.flightId): flight
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. May I know in which file I need to add this? Can`t we get one single output for the input parameter given only by using RAML file?

Comment: Are you asking about mocking the API or an actual implementation?